# How do I find what's hanging up my AJAX call and fix it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

All of a sudden an AJAX call that was working fine a few days ago is currently hanging on my website. I'm not sure how to track this problem down anymore. Because this website is on WordPress, I thought maybe the 4.2.2 update screwed things up. But I reverted back to an older version, which didn't fix it.

[image: Check out the white space in the network timeline, I'm not sure what's causing this.]

XHR:
[image: Timeline with XHR types only]

What's going on? When I click a menu item, it makes an AJAX call to admin-ajax.php and then it hangs for about 30 seconds with no client-side activity until the rest of the requests are made. I imagine, that the hang up is happening on the server but I'm not sure how to prove that.

Here's the function with my AJAX call in it:

```
        function loadAjax(id, pageOrder) {
            ajaxCalled = true;
             jQuery('.side-menu').fadeIn(200, function () {
                 jQuery(this).find('li.current-menu-item').removeClass('current-menu-item');
                 jQuery(this).find('li').eq(parseInt(pageOrder)).addClass('current-menu-item');
            });
            jQuery.post(
                    ajaxurl, // link to wp-ajax.php usually generated within a theme, if not, create manually
                    {
                        action: 'get_subpages', // Action in functions.php  ajax function
                        id: id    // parameter sent
                    },
                function (response) {
                    //////console.log('response received');
                    if (response !== "0") {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            jQuery('.ajax-loader').removeClass('loading');
                            jQuery('.ajax-loader').addClass('loaded');
                        }, 1500);
                        jQuery(".ajax-content").html(response);
                        defaultPageSetFigureHeight(windowHeight);
                        featureSidebar();
                        pullSubpages();
                        var title = jQuery('.ajax-content .content').attr('data-title');
                        jQuery('.logo .page').html(title);
                    }
                });
                jQuery(window).unbind('touchend touchstart wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup').unbind(handlers);
            }
            function updateURL(urlPath) {
                history.pushState('data', '', urlPath);
            }
            function detectEndScroll() {
                jQuery(window).scroll(jQuery.debounce(200, function () {
                    scrollDetected = parseInt(scrollTop / windowHeight); // This needed to balance on scrolling 
                    //alert(scrollTop);
                    if (scrollAction === 'scroll') {
                        var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
                        if (!isiPad) {
                            postionPages(); // Do not remove. Bug fix
                        }
                    }
                }));
            }
            function postionPages() {
                if (!isMobile()) {
                    scrollAction === 'disable';
                    scrollTopBeforeScrolling = scrollDetected * windowHeight;

                    //console.log("CURRENT: " + scrollTop + " BEFORE: " + scrollTopBeforeScrolling);
                    if (scrollTop > scrollTopBeforeScrolling) {
                        direction = 'down';
                    } else {
                        direction = 'up';
                    }
                    var module = scrollTop % windowHeight;
                    var diff = module / windowHeight;
                    if (diff > 0.15 && direction === 'down') {
                        scrollDetected++;
                    }
                    if (diff > 0.75 && direction === 'up') {
                        scrollDetected--;
                    }
                    //console.log("MODULE " + module + " scrollTop: " + scrollTop + " windowHeight: " + windowHeight + " Scroll: " + scrollDetected + ' DIRECTION: ' + direction);
                    if (scrollTop % windowHeight !== 0) {
                        if (!ajaxCalled) {
                            var skip = scrollDetected *  parseInt(windowHeight);
                            animateFastScrolling(skip);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here's the `get_subpages` action being called in `functions.php`:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_get_subpages", "get_subpages");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_subpages", "get_subpages");

function get_subpages() {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $post = get_post($id);
    $pageContent = $post->post_content;
    $pageTitle = $post->post_title;
    $subpageOpen = get_post_meta($id, "mbe_subpage_open", 1);
    ?>
    <div class="container content alignCenter" data-title="<?php echo $pageTitle; ?>">
        <?php
        echo apply_filters('the_content', $pageContent);
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    $subpages = get_post_meta($post->ID, "mbe_subpages_", 0);
    $subpageArray = array();
    foreach ($subpages as $element) {
        $element = explode("-", $element);
        $subpageIDstring = $element[1];
        array_push($subpageArray, $subpageIDstring);
    }
    $parameters = implode(',', $subpageArray);
    global $wpdb;
    $subpagesResults = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `ID` IN (" . $parameters . ") AND `post_type` LIKE 'page' ORDER BY `wp_posts`.`menu_order` DESC");
    createMapPopups();
    foreach ($subpagesResults as $subpage) {
        $subpageID = $subpage->ID;
        $isHero = get_post_meta($subpageID, 'mbe_hero', 1);
        $isMap = get_post_meta($subpageID, 'mbe_map', 1);
        $blueMapType = get_post_meta($subpageID, 'mbe_map_blue_type', 0);
        $slug = $subpage->post_name;
        $isMapHistoric = get_post_meta($subpageID, 'mbe_map_historic', 1);
        ?>
        <div class="wrapper figure subfigure <?php echo($isMap == 1 || $isMapHistoric == 1 ? "map relative notMobile" : "notmap"); ?> <?php echo ($subpageOpen == 1 ? "openStatic" : ""); ?>" id="<?php echo $slug; ?>" data-url="<?php echo get_permalink($pageID); ?>" >
            <?php
            $title = $subpage->post_title;
            $content = $subpage->post_content;
            $excerpt = get_custom_excerpt($subpage, 30, ' ... <a href="#" class="more">(Read More)</a>');
            $featured_image_url_subpage = "";

            if (has_post_thumbnail($subpageID)) {
                $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($subpageID), 'full');
                $image_width = $image[1];
                $image_height = $image[2];
                $featured_image_url_subpage = $image[0];
                if ($isHero == 1) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="wrapper figure main" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $featured_image_url_subpage; ?>)">
                    </div>
                <?php } else if ($isMap == 1) { ?>
                    <div class="map-outer">
                        <img src="<?php echo $featured_image_url_subpage; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="Map" />
                        <?php createMarkers($blueMapType); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                } else if ($isMapHistoric == 1) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="map-outer">
                        <img src="<?php echo $featured_image_url_subpage; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="Map" />
                <?php
                createHistoricMarkers();
                ?>
                    </div>
                        <?php
                        createHistoricMapPopups();
                    } else {
                        ?>
                    <div class="img relative top overflowHidden" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $featured_image_url_subpage; ?>)">
                    </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
        if ($isHero != 1 && $isMap != 1 && $isMapHistoric != 1) {
            ?>
                <div class="wrapper relative">
                    <header class="wrapper float absolute">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="header-top container">
                                <div class="no-padding col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="bar">
                                        <div class="item bar-bottom"></div>
                                        <div class="item bar-top"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="action col-sm-2">
                                    <div class="share">(Share)
            <?php createSocialPopup($title, $excerpt, $slug) ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="close"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h2 class="container title noafter"><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
                        </div>
                    </header>
                    <header class="wrapper normal">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="header-top container">
                                <div class="no-padding col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="bar">
                                        <div class="item bar-bottom"></div>
                                        <div class="item bar-top"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="action col-sm-2">
                                    <div class="share">(Share)</div>
                                    <div class="close"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h2 class="container title noafter"><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
                        </div>
                    </header>
                </div>
                <div class="container content">

                    <div class="description">
                        <div class="excerpt">
            <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $excerpt); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="full transition4">
            <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $content); ?>
                            <div class="bottom baseline"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php }
        ?>
        </div>
            <?php
        }

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'feature',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        );
        $featuresCategory = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mbe_feature_');
        if (!empty($featuresCategory)) {
            ?>
        <div class="wrapper figure featureWrapper overflowHidden">
            <div class="wrapper left">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper right">
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="sidebar-holder no-padding col-sm-4 notMobile">
                    <div class="sidebar <?php echo(count($featuresCategory) > 1 ? 'double' : '' ); ?> feature-left">
        <?php
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($featuresCategory as $category) {
            $category = explode("-", $category);
            $categoryID = $category[1];
            $categoryName = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_terms` WHERE `term_id` = $categoryID");
            $categoryName = $categoryName[0]->name;
            ?>
                            <h2 class="title"><?php echo strtoupper($categoryName); ?></h2>
                            <ul>
            <?php
            $args = array('showposts' => -1, 'post_type' => 'feature', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'feature-category',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms' => $categoryID)
            ));
            $features = get_posts($args);
            foreach ($features as $feature) {
                $title = $feature->post_title;
                $slug = $feature->post_name;
                ?>
                                    <li><a class="<?php echo($count === 0 ? "active" : ""); ?>" href="#<?php echo $slug ?>" data-id="<?php echo $slug ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a></li>
                                    <?php
                                    $count++;
                                }
                                ?>
                            </ul>
                            <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="feature no-padding content col-sm-8">
        <?php
        $zindex = 0;
        foreach ($featuresCategory as $category) {
            $category = explode("-", $category);
            $categoryID = $category[1];

            $args = array('showposts' => -1, 'post_type' => 'feature', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'feature-category',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms' => $categoryID)
            ));
            $features = get_posts($args);
            foreach ($features as $feature) {
                $title = $feature->post_title;
                $slug = $feature->post_name;
                $url = get_permalink($feature->ID);
                $content = $feature->post_content;
                $excerpt = $feature->post_excerpt;
                $featured_img = "";
                if (has_post_thumbnail($feature->ID)) {
                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($feature->ID), 'full');
                    $image_width = $image[1];
                    $image_height = $image[2];
                    $featured_img = $image[0];
                }
                ?>
                            <div class="story" data-id="<?php echo $slug; ?>" style="z-index: 990<?php echo $zindex++; ?>">
                                <div class="relative">
                                    <header class="float notMobile">
                                        <div class="first">
                <?php if (!empty($featured_img)) { ?><img src="<?php echo $featured_img; ?>" class="img-responsive" width="186" alt="dow"/><?php } ?>
                                            <h2 class="noafter"><?php echo $title ?></h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </header>
                                    <header>
                                        <div class="container second">
                <?php if (!empty($featured_img)) { ?><img src="<?php echo $featured_img; ?>" class="img-responsive" width="186" alt="dow"/><?php } ?>
                                            <h2 class="noafter"><?php echo $title ?></h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </header>
                                </div>
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="excerpt"><?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $excerpt); ?></div>
                                    <div class="storyContent"><?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $content); ?></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
            <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper footer posts">
    <?php
    $menuItems = getMenuItems(2);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($menuItems); $i++) {
        if (intval($menuItems[$i]->object_id) == $post->ID) {
            if ($i > 0) {
                $previous = $menuItems[$i - 1];
                $previous = $previous->object_id;
                $previous = get_post($previous);
            } else {
                $previous = $menuItems[count($menuItems) - 1];
                $previous = $previous->object_id;
                $previous = get_post($previous);
            }
            if ($i >= count($menuItems) - 1) {
                $next = $menuItems[0]->object_id;
                $next = get_post($next);
            } else {
                $next = $menuItems[$i + 1];
                $next = $next->object_id;
                $next = get_post($next);
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
            <div class="item col-xs-6 previous alignRight">
                <div class="button">
                    <div class="top">
                        Previous:
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($previous->ID); ?>"> <?php echo $previous->post_title; ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item col-xs-6 next alignLeft">
                <div class="button">
                    <div class="top">
                        Next:
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($next->ID); ?>"><?php echo $next->post_title; ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer download-report">
            <div class="item">
                <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Report.pdf" target="_blank">DOWNLOAD FULL REPORT</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    die();
}
```

Could this be caused by a memory leak? If so, I have a hard time tracking it down. Or is this happening in the PHP somewhere?

It's probably obvious, but I admit, I'm not quite sure what I'm doing. I didn't write all this code myself originally, but I'm in charge of the website now. Let me know if there's anymore information I can supply you all with. Thanks.

**UPDATE 6/12/15:** We found out that the AJAX process works fine when we revert our WordPress version back to 4.1.5 — this must mean one of the recent WordPress updates broke it then, yeah?

Comment: Can you please take another screenshot from the inspector? Press the XHR button so that it only shows ajax requests.

Comment: @maxcal Added it to the post, it's below the original network timeline screenshot. Thanks for looking into this :) I imagine the image doesn't help though considering it's only doing one thing.

Comment: test with a simple echo statement in your php code. I doubt its a memory leak on the code, unless your php mem is set really low or there are a huge amount of posts, but it would be worth checking the php code outside of ajax if there are no errors in the console.   I'd be surprised though if its not a javascript error.

Comment: @David, thanks for the tip. I'll try that out. I added another update above stating that the build works fine when I revert back to an older version of WordPress...

Comment: well the change log is here https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_4.2, if you have a older wp install (of below 3.8???) the scripts used to be added in the header by default, now its the footer, so if your js function is still in the header and jquery is in the footer...the above may not be the only ajax on the page.